# Center block-grid for mobile in portrait AND landscape in Foundation 4

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I'm using Foundation 4 and I have a block grid that looks the way I want it to in portrait on my iPhone 5 (ios7), but when i turn it to landscape, it's a mess.  For some reason it doesn't center anything that I have centered in portrait.

```
<div class="row"><!-- for centering -->
<div class="small-12 large-8 small-centered columns">

<div class="row">
  <div class="small-12 large-8 small-centered columns" style="text-align:center;">
  <h3 id="makemebold"><small>some long text about why my site is great<small></h3>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="small-12 large-8 small-centered columns">
  <a href="shopping_list" class="greencallout">
     Hey, User, Get Started! Woohoo!</a></div>
</div>

<div class="row">&nbsp;</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="small-12 large-6 small-centered columns">
<ul id="board" class="small-block-grid-2 large-block-grid-8" >
   <li><a id="login_a" class="mobile_buttons" href="#" 
        title="Click here to Login">Login|Register</a></li>
   <li><a id='makemebold' class="mobile_buttons" href="learn">Learn More</a></li>
   <li><a href="profile" class="mobile_buttons" >Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact" class="mobile_buttons">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>

</div>
</div><!-- end of centering div -->
```

The "long text about why my site is great" IS centered.  But when flipped to landscape, it doesn't get any bigger and doesn't seem to change to the large-8 setting.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind.  I just added  style="text-align:center;" to each of the div tags that wasn't centering and it fixed the problem.